# Why doesn't installing the Intel MKL from the Intel repository add the MKL to the linker path?

Tags: apt, 18.04, intel

I'm running 18.04 (LTS) and regretting it (b/c the latest Ubuntu has Intel MKL in the official repos). To install the MKL I tried following the instructions on the [Intel webpage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo)

And now I have their repo added and I have a `deb https://apt.repos.intel.com/mkl all main` added to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

This allowed me to install the `intel-mkl-64bit-2019.3-062 2019.3-062` package

Not sure if this is related, but `apt` doesn't allow me to install the `intel-mkl-64bit` package

```
geokon@ux305-neon:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install intel-mkl-64bit
[sudo] password for geokon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package intel-mkl-64bit is a virtual package provided by:
  intel-mkl-64bit-2019.3-062 2019.3-062
  intel-mkl-64bit-2019.2-057 2019.2-057
  intel-mkl-64bit-2019.1-053 2019.1-053
  intel-mkl-64bit-2019.0-045 2019.0-045
  intel-mkl-64bit-2018.4-057 2018.4-057
  intel-mkl-64bit-2018.3-051 2018.3-051
  intel-mkl-64bit-2018.2-046 2018.2-046
  intel-mkl-64bit-2018.1-038 2018.1-038
  intel-mkl-64bit-2018.0-033 2018.0-033
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'intel-mkl-64bit' has no installation candidate
```

Now I see all the libraries in `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/` and so far so good

```
geokon@ux305-neon:~/Downloads$ ls /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.3.199/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/ -la
total 1754936
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 4月  11 17:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 4月  11 17:42 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  56865848 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_avx2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  75828554 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_avx512_mic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  70221251 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_avx512.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  52563274 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_avx.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1241940 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    499647 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    737654 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    302138 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1261348 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    500791 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_openmpi_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    757062 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    307346 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1241356 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_sgimpt_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    499968 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_sgimpt_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    737070 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_sgimpt_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    302427 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_blacs_sgimpt_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    661612 1月  25 15:00 libmkl_blas95_ilp64.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    657092 1月  25 15:00 libmkl_blas95_lp64.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    219074 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_cdft_core.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    169424 1月  25 15:36 libmkl_cdft_core.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 658813494 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_core.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  70211598 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_core.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  40846834 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_def.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23997000 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_gf_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10395785 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_gf_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25047306 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_gf_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11106101 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_gf_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  32978900 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_gnu_thread.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  24745269 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_gnu_thread.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24167784 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_intel_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10450976 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_intel_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25218272 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_intel_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11161292 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_intel_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52711696 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_intel_thread.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  39834096 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_intel_thread.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7412440 1月  25 15:02 libmkl_lapack95_ilp64.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7337296 1月  25 15:01 libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  48549670 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_mc3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  47198814 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_mc.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59714172 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_pgi_thread.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  39520774 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_pgi_thread.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6628244 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_rt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11932372 1月  25 15:38 libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   7551896 1月  25 15:38 libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12011424 1月  25 15:37 libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   7561589 1月  25 15:38 libmkl_scalapack_lp64.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26833248 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_sequential.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21550546 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_sequential.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39794824 1月  25 15:23 libmkl_tbb_thread.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27588476 1月  25 15:35 libmkl_tbb_thread.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  12572548 1月  25 15:31 libmkl_vml_avx2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  13736102 1月  25 15:33 libmkl_vml_avx512_mic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  12308583 1月  25 15:34 libmkl_vml_avx512.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  12594933 1月  25 15:30 libmkl_vml_avx.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6372358 1月  25 15:25 libmkl_vml_cmpt.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   6745690 1月  25 15:24 libmkl_vml_def.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11333369 1月  25 15:28 libmkl_vml_mc2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11411109 1月  25 15:29 libmkl_vml_mc3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11393390 1月  25 15:27 libmkl_vml_mc.so
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 4月  11 17:41 locale
```

But when I run a program that needs to link to them they can't be found bc this path has clearly not been added to the LD search path

Is this an issue with Intel's repo and how it installs/configures the package?  I'm not sure how to debug the issue further on my own. I'd rather not do `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hacks especially if this is symptomatic of a larger issue

Comment: Yes IMHO it's an issue with Intel's repo and how it installs/configures the package - you will need to follow the post-installation steps, for example [Scripts to Set Environment Variables](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-scripts-to-set-environment-variables)